# Single input variable for windows send to .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, right-click

I want to get a framemd5 via ffmpeg by right clicking a file, selecting "send to", then selecting my.bat file.

Using this allows me to make framemd5s for every file in a directory:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do C:\Users\bla\Downloads\avanti-092\Avanti-ffmpeg-GUI-092\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -f framemd5 "%%~na.framemd5"pause
```

I want to just run the bat file on a single file, the one I right clicked on to begin with. I do not know which variable to use.

Comment: Use `%1` in your batch file to access the right-clicked/sent-to file. This works on a single file only. See `call /?` for help.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Here's my command: `for %%a in (%1) do C:\Users\bla\Downloads\avanti-092\Avanti-ffmpeg-GUI-092\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %%a -f framemd5 "%%~na.framemd5"`
pause

Comment: Also I want to accept your answer and give you rep but I don't see the option. is this because you commented rather than selecting "answer question"?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's because of comments. I just wanted to make sure to understand your question correctly before I provida an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Send-To command (the batch file in your case) receives the selected file(s) as command line argument(s), which can be accessed in a batch file with `%1`, `%2`, `%3` and so on.
`%0` is the (path to the) batch file itself. Type `call /?` to get more information.

For applying that to a single file use `%1`. This syntax supports `~` modifiers like `for` variables. For instance, `%~1` removes surrounding double-quotes, `%~n1` extracts the file name only.

For your batch file, you actually don't need the `for` command (which executed one iteration only).

The following should therefore work:

```
C:\Users\bla\Downloads\avanti-092\Avanti-ffmpeg-GUI-092\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\ffmpeg-20150513-git-51f6455-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -f framemd5 "%~n1.framemd5" & pause
```

Comment: Even better. yes, the for loop was redundant. So I can have multiple files in a batch by using %1 and %2? I have another question about this that I think you can answer, might as well make a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639056/multiple-inputs-in-a-windows-batch-file-using-fc

Comment: Exactly, that's true, you can access up to 9 command line arguments like that (`%1` to `%9`); if you have got more, type `shift /?`...