# Multiple inputs in a windows batch file using FC

Tags: windows, batch-file, diff

I am hoping to use a windows "send-to" .bat file to run a differential between two text files using the FC command line tool.

My current batch is: `fc "%1" "%2" pause`

All FC requires from the command line is `FC file1 file2`

I want to select two text files and run them through the batch file via send-to.

Comment: You could have the batch memorize the filename in the first call and compare it when you call the batch the second time

Comment: How would that batch look? Is there a way to just select both files and have FC process the command via batch file?

Comment: You would need to do some coding in order to extend the context menu. Have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088510/implement-explorer-contextmenu-and-pass-multiple-files-to-one-program-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both files are in the same folder:

```
@fc "%~1" "%~2" & pause
```